# Current electricity basics

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits

As we know that current flows from a point of higher potential to lower potential,so consider a diagram shown below how do you justify the flow of current between points 1 and 2,since they are at same potential.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Potential differences can give rise to electric fields which accelerate charges.  In the absence of electric fields (or other forces), charges don't accelerate.

By saying 1 and 2 are at the same potential, we assume the use of ideal wires ($R=0$).  In such a wire, potential differences aren't needed to maintain current, only set it up.

When the circuit was created, then there would have been temporary electric fields moving through the circuit as charges redistribute and the circuit approaches its long-term state.   During this transitory period, point 1 would have had a higher potential than point 2, and charges would have been accelerated to the steady-state current.

In the non-ideal case (real wires with real resistance), then points 1 and 2 don't have the same potential and there's no surprise.

Answer (score 0):

Good question! Basic, and *so* important to understand.

You say two things right:

- Charge wants to go towards a point at lower potential.
- There is no potential difference between your points 1 and 2, so there is no driving potential here.

Now put these two facts together:

1. A charge arriving at the resistor from the top, is squeezed through it and ends up at the lower potential on the other side of the resistor.
2. **Another charges does the same.**
3. Like charges repel, so this new charge will push the other charge further ahead.
4. Many, many charges repeat this and pass through the resistor. The flow of charges on the other side of the resistor is caused by the the push from the next ones that want to pass through as well.

If this did not happen, there wouldn't be any charge arriving at the resistor in the first place. The key points are: A potential difference is a "push" that drives the current in the circuit, but places with no potential difference are simply "following" along and the flow there will be what ever the rest of the circuit causes.